# How do I make a CSS attribute wildcard selector over look semantic tags?

Tags: html, css

I was going through an example on a simple CSS grid layout  (https://css-tricks.com/dont-overthink-it-grids/), and realized that if I had a `<article class="col-2-3"></article>` and `<aside class="col-1-3"><aside>`in the same row, my attribute selector `[class*="col-"]:last-of-type {padding-right: 0;}` was selecting both semantic tags, not just the aside.

Is there a way not to revert back to `<div>`s, and use an attribute wildcard selector for just the last type?

Comment: There's more than one way to skin a cat, you are not limited to just `*`. You have not mentioned of which one you preferred to pick : `<article>` or `<aside>` and I suggest you provide a [mcve]. Your selector has `:last-of-type` which means the whole page must be known in order to determine if a `nth` selector is effective or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:last-of-type` is selecting both because the types of your 2 elements is *article* and *aside*, I believe the tutorial you are using uses only *div* which are of the same type.

Try using `[class*="col-"]:last-child` if you're determined to keep article and aside.